# Why I am getting this type of error? at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:94)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, jar

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
   
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Navigate to google.com
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
     }
}
```

I am getting such error for above program:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging
> implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using
> SimpleLogger to log to the console... Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher     at
> org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager.configureBootstraps(ChannelManager.java:212)
> at
> org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:94)
> at org.asynchttpclient.Dsl.asyncHttpClient(Dsl.java:32)     at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:94)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.(NettyClient.java:47)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:135)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:116)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:94)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:88)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:40)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriver.java:111)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:101)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:88)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:84)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:52)
> at script.Practice.main(Practice.java:12) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 16 more

Could not run any automation script

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher

This means you are missing the library org.reactivestreams. You are also missing the log4-core library on your classpath.